# Can I make myself have original thoughts?

Tags: achievements, everything

There are a few trophies/achievements such as "Thinker" and "The Big Thinker," which seem to be awarded for thinking a certain number of your own thoughts.

I've noticed very rarely that I have thoughts appear underneath me that are a jumbled mess of other things' thoughts that I've seen or heard up to that point, but these are few and far between and show up without any sort of pattern. Is there anything I can do to make myself have my own thoughts more regularly, or do I just think things completely randomly?

Comment: Is "Everything" the title of a game? The tag has no description, and without it, this question seems very philosophical. :)

Comment: @T.J.L. Yeah, it's a new tag so tag wiki yet... [Here is the Wikipedia page though](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_(video_game)).

Answer (score 3):

As described in [this post](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/187813-everything/75177919) on Gamefaqs, in order to trigger this achievement you can:

- under Autoplay settings, set "Think" to III (3) and everything else to zero (0)
- collect a dozen of thoughts from other entities (those not under your direct control)
- let the game autoplay: it will generate thoughts, and the white ones (yours) will be automatically collected

Several players in this same post reported that the achievement is awarded after an accumulation of thoughts:

> Finally got it. Only had four active thoughts at the time. It's just
>   about the total number.

The number of those is not known, some are guessing around 50.

Autoplay is not needed to complete this achievement (as stated in the comments). But it is a lot easier in doing so.

Comment: Minor note: I've since gotten this trophy as well as had a friend get it. While Autoplay removes the effort from getting this trophy, it most definitely is not required to obtain it.

Comment: @Vemonus I edited the answer to include your comment. Is the question solved now?